# auth0 callback url does not exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, auth0

So i am basically following this auth0 tutorial:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core/01-login

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-mvc-samples/tree/master/Quickstart/01-Login

on my localhost and my test-environment the login completely works. 
Although the error i am getting now on my staging environment also rings a bell, and had that before. But I do not know how I fixed it at that point.

During logging in it gets redirect to the callback url => `callback`, and not following my redirect url as i am setting it.

as in the `accountcontroller`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("login")]
public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/home")
{
    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(Auth0Constants.Auth0Scheme, new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = returnUrl
    });
}
```

so the big question; what am I missing?

EDIT:
looking at the network traffic:
the one that does work:

[image: working-auth0]

I see that I have 2 authorize calls (not sure why?).

and in the one that is not working:

[image: not-working-auth0]

where does the second Login call come from..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was due to the encryption. When running multiple instances the encryption key is different:

when keeping track of the key it is fixed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Auth0 but does it have the URL for each environment?